# Loading visual studio solution gives unhandled exception in designer: "Could not find a part of the path (file path)"

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-trace, windows-forms-designer, designer

I load my project and then these two windows pop up, one after the other (I explain first window below):

[image: First window]

[image: Second window]

But sometimes the second window that shows is this one:

[image: Second window]

However, there is a pattern to which of the two second windows shows.

I noticed that if I load my solution by double-clicking the solution file in file explorer > solution location on the drive (not in visual studio, file > open), then the second window that shows references the G drive (my pen drive which has the solution on it).

However, if I load the solution by loading visual studio then selecting file > open and select the solution (on the same G drive) then the second window that shows references the C drive.

The first window that shows indicates, supposedly, that a method is called within a user control which is in the main form, whenever the solution is loaded:

```
private void EndQuiz()
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        questionNumber = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("You finished the quiz with " + score + " score", "Complete");
        score = 0;
    }
```

This user control's class with the EndQuiz() method (you will find it about half way down):

```
public partial class QuizUC : UserControl
{
    public Label LabelTheme { get { return labelTheme; } }
    public Label LabelQuestionNumber { get { return labelQuestionNumber; } }
    public Label LabelQuestion { get { return labelQuestion; } }
    public Label LabelScore { get { return labelScore; } }

    public Button BtnOption1 { get { return btnOption1; } }
    public Button BtnOption2 { get { return btnOption2; } }
    public Button BtnOption3 { get { return btnOption3; } }
    public Button BtnOption4 { get { return btnOption4; } }

    public PictureBox PictureBox1 { get { return pictureBox1; } }

    Random rnd;
    Bitmap quizImage;

    public string correctAnswer;

    int correctAnswerNo = 0, questionsAsked = 0, questionNumber, rndQuestionNo, score;
    string question, answer;
    string[] individualAnswers;
    bool isOver = false;

    List<string> questions;
    List<int> usedQuestions;
    List<string> answers;

    private int _noOfQuestions;
    private string _selectedTheme = "";

    // quiz not loading on second time DONE
    // selected 5 questions, gave 6 DONE
    // duplicate questions
    // label question overlapping with buttons

    public QuizUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowAll()
    {
        labelTheme.Show();
        labelQuestion.Show();
        labelQuestionNumber.Show();
        btnOption1.Show();
        btnOption2.Show();
        btnOption3.Show();
        btnOption4.Show();
        labelScore.Show();
        pictureBox1.Show();
    }

    public void SetUpVariables(int noOfQuestions, string selectedTheme)
    {
        _noOfQuestions = noOfQuestions < 5 || noOfQuestions > 15 ? 5 : noOfQuestions;
        _selectedTheme = selectedTheme ?? "";
    }

    private void QuizUC_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Visible)
        {
            SetUpQuiz();
        }
    }

    private void QuizUC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadQuestionsAndAnswersFromFile();
    }

    private void SetUpQuiz()
    {
        SetLabelSizes(); // question text will not go off the edge
        labelScore.Text = "Score: 0";
        SetTransparency();
        SetQuestionNumber();

        usedQuestions = new List<int>();

        questionsAsked = 0;
        questionNumber = 1;
        score = 0;

        RandomiseQuestion();
        labelTheme.Text = "Theme: Space";
        labelQuestionNumber.Text = $"Question number: {questionNumber}";

        quizImage = new Bitmap("solarsystem.jpg");
        pictureBox1.Image = quizImage;
    }

    private void ReadQuestionsAndAnswersFromFile()
    {
        string questionFile = "quiz/questions.txt", answerFile = "quiz/answers.txt";
        questions = File.ReadAllLines(questionFile).ToList();
        answers = File.ReadAllLines(answerFile).ToList();
    }

    private void SetLabelSizes()
    {
        labelQuestion.MaximumSize = new Size(labelQuestion.Width, 0);
        labelQuestion.AutoSize = true;
    }

    public void SetTransparency()
    {
        labelQuestion.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        labelTheme.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        labelQuestionNumber.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        labelScore.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    public void SetQuestionNumber()
    {
        labelQuestionNumber.Text = "Question number: " + questionNumber;
    }

    private void EndQuiz()
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        questionNumber = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("You finished the quiz with " + score + " score", "Complete");
        score = 0;
    }

    public void ResetQuiz()
    {
        questionsAsked = 0;
        score = 0;
        labelScore.Text = "Score " + score;
        questionNumber = 1;
        questions = File.ReadAllLines("quiz/questions.txt").ToList();
        answers = File.ReadAllLines("quiz/answers.txt").ToList();
        usedQuestions.Clear();
    }

    public void RandomiseQuestion()
    {
        questionsAsked++;
        if (questionsAsked == _noOfQuestions + 1)
        {
            EndQuiz();
            ResetQuiz();
            return;
        }
        rnd = new Random();

        // ShowAll();
        rndQuestionNo = rnd.Next(0, questions.Count);

        question = questions.Count == 1 ? questions[0] : questions[rndQuestionNo];
        answer = answers[rndQuestionNo];

        questions.RemoveAt(rndQuestionNo);
        answers.RemoveAt(rndQuestionNo);

        individualAnswers = answer.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < individualAnswers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (individualAnswers[i].Contains('*'))
            {
                correctAnswerNo = i;
            }
        }

        individualAnswers[correctAnswerNo] = individualAnswers[correctAnswerNo].Trim('*');
        correctAnswer = individualAnswers[correctAnswerNo];

        labelQuestion.Text = question;
        btnOption1.Text = individualAnswers[0];
        btnOption2.Text = individualAnswers[1];
        btnOption3.Text = individualAnswers[2];
        btnOption4.Text = individualAnswers[3];
    }

    private void IncreaseScore(int score)
    {
        labelScore.Text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }

    private bool CheckToReturn()
    {
        var noOfQuestions = Single.GetSingle().AskHowManyQuestionsForm.NoOfQuestions;

        if (questionNumber == noOfQuestions)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void btnOption1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnOption1.Text == correctAnswer)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct answer!", "Correct");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            score++;
            IncreaseScore(score);
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect answer!", "Incorrect");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
    }

    private void btnOption2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnOption2.Text == correctAnswer)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct answer!", "Correct");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            score++;
            IncreaseScore(score);
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect answer!", "Incorrect");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
    }

    private void btnOption3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnOption3.Text == correctAnswer)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct answer!", "Correct");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            score++;
            IncreaseScore(score);
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect answer!", "Incorrect");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
    }

    private void btnOption4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnOption4.Text == correctAnswer)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct answer!", "Correct");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            score++;
            IncreaseScore(score);
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect answer!", "Incorrect");
            questionNumber++;
            SetQuestionNumber();
            isOver = CheckToReturn();
            RandomiseQuestion();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I open the Menu design window in visual studio, this shows:

[image: Menu design error]

What could be the issue here? I apologise if I haven't included all the code necessary, please tell me what else I should include if I need to. I appreciate that you read all this.

Edit: check comments for more info.

Also, before I had a grey background in here but now the form looks like this, with the error message behind (I dragged a different control out of the way which is not QuizUC, as explained in the comments it disappeared from design view):

[image: Menu design screen error]

Comment: I should add that the application itself runs fine.

Comment: You should add a check if the code is run in design mode and not load any external files when that happens. Your code is also run when designing the forms and if you open files or do other operations they may cause issues. https://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/395658

Comment: Non-Mouse, non-Keyboard events of your control will raise at design-time as well. In `QuizUC_Load` check `if(!DesignMode)`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I put `if(!DesignMode)` and the condition was met inside the `QuizUC_Load` method.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen whenever I dragged about the `QuizUC` user control in the form, messages showed as if the code was running in the program. Then the control disappeared from the design.

Comment: I have noticed that whenever I drag the `QuizUC` on to the form design, I get window 1 to pop up again (you finished quiz with 0 score).

Comment: @itzgeez All you should know is shared with you, you know the code is running in design-time as well as run-time. So just make sure you have written your code in a way that prevent running the logic at design-time. Then close all designer windows and clean and rebuild the solution. Then the problem should be solved.

Comment: When you are trying to learn something new, start by a clean environment and a really easy user control which for example contains just a `MessageBox` in its load event. Also when you post a question, it's better to not post 300 lines of code, instead try to post a [MCVE]. M in the MCVE is important.